# flask url_for behind a reverse proxy

Tags: flask, reverse-proxy, cas

I have a flask application running on a server (`192.168.1.1:8080`) located behind a **reverse proxy**. Let's say, the url `https://foo.bar.com/myapp` point to my flask app, i.e. to `192.168.1.1:8080`.

I am in trouble with the `url_for` flask function, as it returns something like `http://192.168.1.1:8080/blabla` (giving `blabla` as parameter).
How to proceed so that `url_for` returns `https://foo.bar.com/myapp/blabla` instead ?

In fact, my application uses a CAS authentication system. So that the *ticket* gets validate by the CAS server, I need to provide an URL of the shape `https://foo.bar.com/...`.

Any help would be appreciate.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution using `ProxyFix` from `werkzeug` :

```
from werkzeug.middleware.proxy_fix import ProxyFix
app.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(app.wsgi_app, x_host=1)
```

Comment: It's worth pointing out that you need to specify `x_prefix=1` when initialize `ProxyFix` and also in your reverse proxy, such as NGINX, set the header `X-Forwarded-Prefix` to `myapp`.